# Mapbox-gl in a Vue.js single file component (Quasar-Framework)

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, mapbox-gl-js, vue-component

I would like to implement a Mapbox-gl-js Map within a Quasar Framework (Vue) single file component, but I do not get it working. I found some code on Googlemaps with Vue, and some stuff on Mapbox with React, and try to pull it together from that. With below map initialisation parameters I can get the map showing fine in the index.html (with the mapzen tiles), but want it in the component.

I try to follow this [https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/google-maps-and-vue-js](link url) and then adjust it for Mapbox:
*proj/src/components/maplayout.vue :*

```
<template>
    <quasar-layout>
      <h3>Map</h3>
      <div id='map'></div>
    </quasar-layout>
  </template>

  <script>
  import mapboxgl from '../app'

  export default {
    data () {
      return {}
    },
    create () {
      this.createMap()
    },
    methods: {
      createMap: function () {
        mapboxgl.accessToken = '{{yourmapboxaccestokenkey}}'
        var simple = {
          'version': 8,
          'sources': {
            'osm': {
              'type': 'vector',
              'tiles': ['https://vector.mapzen.com/osm/all/{z}/{x}/{y}.mvt?api_key=vector-tiles-{{yourmapzenapikey}}']
            }
          },
          'layers': [{
            'id': 'background',
            'type': 'background',
            'paint': {
              'background-color': '#adddd2'
            }
          }, {
            'id': 'majorroad',
            'source': 'osm',
            'source-layer': 'roads',
            'type': 'line'
          }, {
            'id': 'buildings',
            'type': 'fill',
            'source': 'osm',
            'source-layer': 'buildings'
          }]
        }

        // initialize the map
        this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
          container: 'map',
          style: simple,
          center: [-1.83, -78.183],
          zoom: 5.5
        })
      }
    }
  }
  </script>

  <style>
  </style>
```

By the way, for mapbox with webpack you need certain loaders, see:
[https://mikewilliamson.wordpress.com/2016/02/24/using-mapbox-gl-and-webpack-together/](link url)
But as I got Mapbox working with Webpack before (without vue), I think I have that ok. Actually I do not get any errors in the browser console (but obviously no map appears).

In the app.js file I do not know how to deal with the suggested (maybe not necessary as googlemaps needs a callback, dunno about mapbox/mapzen?!):

```
var App = window.App = new Vue ({
//code
})
```

As in Quasar initialization is done like this:

```
Quasar.start(() => {
  Router.start(Vue.extend({}), '#quasar-app')
})
```

Which I do not really get...

Any suggestions how to get this working are welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was close. This actually works:

```
<template>
  <quasar-layout>
  <h3>Map</h3>
  <div id='map'></div>
  </quasar-layout>
</template>

<script>
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl'
console.dir(mapboxgl)

export default {
  data () {
    return {}
  },
  ready () {
    this.createMap()
  },
  methods: {
    createMap: function () {
      mapboxgl.accessToken = '{{yourmapboxaccestokenkey}}'
      var simple = {
        'version': 8,
        'sources': {
          'osm': {
            'type': 'vector',
            'tiles': ['https://vector.mapzen.com/osm/all/{z}/{x}/{y}.mvt?api_key=vector-tiles-{{yourmapzenapikey}}']
          }
        },
        'layers': [{
          'id': 'background',
          'type': 'background',
          'paint': {
            'background-color': '#bbccd2'
          }
        },
          {
            'id': 'majorroad',
            'source': 'osm',
            'source-layer': 'roads',
            'type': 'line'
          },
          {
            'id': 'buildings',
            'type': 'fill',
            'source': 'osm',
            'source-layer': 'buildings'
          }]
      }

      // init the map
      this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: simple,
        minzoom: 1.3,
        center: [-74.0073, 40.7124], // Manhattan
        zoom: 16
      })

      this.map.addControl(new mapboxgl.Navigation())
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

I did not change my Vue initialisation.

Comment: having this.createMap() inside the mounted() will be more appropriate than ready()

Answer (score 2):

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <div id='map'></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';

require('../node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css');

export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data() {
    return {
      apiKey: {{ your api key }},
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.createMap();
  },
  methods: {
    createMap() {
      mapboxgl.accessToken = this.apiKey;
      // init the map
      this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
        minzoom: 1.3,
        center: [-74.0073, 40.7124], // Manhattan
        zoom: 16,
      });

      this.map.addControl(new mapboxgl.Navigation());
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

This might help, I guess!

Answer (score 1):

First thing I noticed: You are initializing the map before DOM is injected into the document. Instead of ‘created()’ method use ‘ready()’.

Comment: Nice to be answered by the founder of Quasar Framework himself!  I follow your suggestion and get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'accessToken' of undefined`. Apparently `mapboxgl` is undefined. I do import the mapbox-gl library in app.js and then `export default mapboxgl` and import it in maplayout.vue .

Comment: Check if mapboxgl is undefined in app.js too. Are you doing manipulations on mapboxgl in app.js? If not, import it directly in your layout instead of proxying it through app.js. Do you have a repo I can take a look on?

Comment: After getting the import of mapboxgl object right I get: Uncaught Error: webworkify-webpack: Could not locate module containing worker function! Make sure you aren't using eval sourcemaps and that you pass named functions to webworkify-webpack! Issue is in following repo: https://github.com/musicformellons/mapcomponent

Comment: I changed the webpack config: `devtool: '#cheap-source-map',` and error above is solved. The map almost seems to show (got a green mapbox canvas), except there is no mapdetails... Not so sure about the `this.map` part but when just doing `map` I get es-lint errors.

Answer (score 1):

Quasar is Based on Vue2 version. So ready method is deprecated so instead of that use mounted method.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution. Please [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5419867/edit) to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead